# Why it is needed to use const A& instead of just A&?

Tags: c++, class, constants

I was wondering why it is needed to use const A& in this situation, Why can't I use just A&?  according to what I read is because it specified that it won't change the object. Is there any other reason? I would like a better explanation.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>

class A{
public:
    int x;
    A(int x=0): x{x} {std::cout<<"Construct"<<std::endl;};
    A(const A& rhs) {x=rhs.x;std::cout<<"Copy"<<std::endl;}
};

bool operator < (const A& lhs,const A& rhs) {return lhs.x<rhs.x;}

int main(){
    std::set<A> Set;
    A a(10);
    Set.insert(a);
    Set.emplace(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you mean in the constructor?

Comment: @pm100 yes, in the constructor.

Comment: If creating a copy of an object  (e.g. defining and initialising `b` as a copy of `a`, via `A b(a);`) one often does not expect the logical state of `a` (the object being copied) to change.   Qualifying the argument of the copy constructor as `const` communicates that is, indeed, the case.   Among other things, this allows creating a temporary (an unnamed object within an expression, and copying the temporary).   If it does make sense for the state of `a` to change, the `const` can be omitted - among other things, that does prevent copying of a temporary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A&` is an lvalue reference, which means it can change the thing it's looking at. With

```
A(A& rhs)
```

you can call it like

```
int x = 10;
A a(x);
```

And then any changes to `rhs` in the constructor will change the *actual* variable `x`. And that's fine. But when you do

```
A a(10);
```

That's a problem. Because if someone changes `rhs` in the constructor, that means we have to "change" the number `10`, and that's not really even a meaningful thing to do. `10 += 1` is nonsense in C++, for instance.

`const A&` is a guarantee that we aren't going to *change* the thing being pointed to, so it becomes safe to pass a temporary value like `10` to the function.

If we knew it was always a "small" datatype like `int`, we might take it by value, but we don't want to take an `A` as argument, since some types (like vectors) can be expensive to copy, and others (like `unique_ptr`) are outright impossible to copy.

Depending on your use case, you can consider using `A&&`, an rvalue reference. This is useful if you intend to *move* the value into the class you're constructing, rather than make a copy of it. You can read more about move semantics on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics), but if you're just starting out in C++, it's probably best to stay away from rvalue references. It is good to be aware that they exist, though.